# Irreducible polynomial that has a multiple zero example

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm probably missing a point in this example, but what does the zero of f(x) look like in $F[x]/\langle x^2-t\rangle$?

Consider $x^2-t\in F[x]/\langle x^2-t\rangle$. Then the roots of $f(x)$ are $\pm\sqrt{t}$, each of multiplicity $1$, and each not belonging to $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)$. What point(s) am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the point you are missing is that $\sqrt{t}=-\sqrt{t}$ because $F[x]$ and its field of fractions has characteristic $2$. There is actually only one root.

Comment: I'm not sure how $\sqrt{t}$ works in a $\mathbb{Z}_2(t)[x]$. Can you please explain? Does $\sqrt{t}$ mean that any polynomial has the form $({a_n {\sqrt{t}^n} + \dots + a_0})b_n x^n + \dots + ({a_n {\sqrt{t}^n}+\dots+a_0)b_0} $, where for $\sqrt{t}$ we can only substitute $1$ or $0$? Then $x^2-t$ has the root $\sqrt{t}$ of multiplicity $2$ because $t=0$ or $t=1$ in this case. Is this correct?

Comment: @sequence I have no idea what you mean in the first half of your comment. In $\mathbb Z_2(t)[x]/(x^2-t)$, the coset $x+(x^2-t)$ satisfies $(x+(x^2-t))^2=t+(x^2-t)$, so $x+(x^2-t)$ is a square root of $t+(x^2-t)$. We just write it as $\sqrt{t}$ as a convenience.